# Replacing checkbox with radio buttons in ext treepanel

Tags: extjs, tree

I have wizard where in have used the treepanel in extjs. Currently I am using the checkbox against node in treepanel, but now i need to replace the checkbox with radio button. PLease suggest something.

Comment: I am using tree.js from extjs liabrary for treepanel

Comment: i tried it by changing xtype: "radiogroup"

Comment: how did you tried that? code please.

Comment: var treeDetailPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
   itemId:'dsTreeDetailPanel',
   border:1,
   items:[xtype: 'radiogroup']
  });

Comment: I think it is more easy to use checkbox and achieve the same function as radiobox, two or three simple method can achieve that.